# Why isn't my event listener callback using the correct state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component to make wrapped elements draggable. When I start dragging, I add event listeners to window for drag movement and drop.

```
    function start_drag({ x, y }) {
        window.addEventListener('mouseup', trigger_drop);
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', drag_move);
        dispatch({ type: DispatchActions.START, x: x, y: y });
    }
```

With these callbacks:

```
    const trigger_drop = (e) => {
        //if (!dragging) { return; }
        end_drag();
        if (deliver()) {
            if (props.onDrop) {
                props.onDrop(e);
            }
        }
    }

    const drag_move = (e) => {
        //if (!state.dragging) { return; }
        dispatch({ type: DispatchActions.MOVE, x: e.x, y: e.y });
        if (props.onDragMove) {
            props.onDragMove(e);
        }
    }
```

However, these callbacks are using their own versions of state and dispatch. After trying a few things I haven't been able to fix this, and in addition I'm confused about the way 'this' is functioning here.

I am working in React, using only functional components with React Hooks for state and so on.
From many other stackoverflow questions the answers have been to use binding/arrow functions. As you can see I'm declaring my callbacks as arrow functions (which isn't working) but this led me to something strange; when I tried binding I found out that `this === undefined` in my functional component. This is probably related. My searches for this only came up with answers saying to bind this in the constructor for a React.Component class, which doesn't work here.

Here is the full code for the module:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useReducer } from 'react';
import { DragContext } from 'client/contexts/DragContext';
import dragtarget from './DragTarget.module.css';


const DispatchActions = {
    MOVE: 'move',
    START: 'start',
    STOP: 'stop'
}

function reducer(state, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case DispatchActions.MOVE: 
            return { ...state, offset_x: action.x - (state.start_x + state.offset_x), offset_y: action.y - (state.start_y + state.offset_y) };
        case DispatchActions.START:
            return { ...state, dragging: true, start_x: action.x, start_y: action.y, offset_x: 0, offset_y: 0 };
        case DispatchActions.STOP:
            return { ...state, dragging: false };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}


export default function DragTarget(props) {
    const { drag, deliver } = useContext(DragContext);
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { 
                                                        dragging: false,
                                                        start_x: 0, start_y: 0,
                                                        offset_x: 0, offset_y: 0 
                                                    });

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            end_drag();
        };
    }, []);


    function start_drag({ x, y }) {
        window.addEventListener('mouseup', trigger_drop);
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', drag_move);
        dispatch({ type: DispatchActions.START, x: x, y: y });
    }

    function end_drag() {
        window.removeEventListener('mouseup', trigger_drop);
        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', drag_move);
        dispatch({ type: DispatchActions.STOP });
    }

    const trigger_drag = (e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        if (drag(props.payload)) {
            start_drag({ x: e.x, y: e.y });
            if (props.onDragStart) {
                props.onDragStart();
            }
        }
    }

    const drag_move = (e) => {
        //if (!state.dragging) { return; }
        dispatch({ type: DispatchActions.MOVE, x: e.x, y: e.y });
        if (props.onDragMove) {
            props.onDragMove(e);
        }
    }

    const trigger_drop = (e) => {
        //if (!state.dragging) { return; }
        end_drag();
        if (deliver()) {
            if (props.onDrop) {
                props.onDrop(e);
            }
        }
    }


    return (
        <div className={`${props.className} ${state.dragging ? dragtarget.dragging : null}`} style={{ transform: `translate(${state.offset_x}px, ${state.offset_y}px)` }} onMouseDown={trigger_drag}>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Expected: On window.mouseup I want the callback trigger_drop to access the correct `state.dragging` and `dispatch`. Same for drag_move on window.mousemove.

Current: On window.mouseup the callback trigger_drop's copy of state.dragging returns `false` (instead of referencing the correct one, which has `true`), and drag_move is dispatching to a state with undefined elements in it (state === `{dragging: true, start_x: undefined, start_y: undefined, offset_x: NaN, offset_y: NaN}`).

I hope I explained this clearly, if not please let me know. Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: I'm not super familiar with React, are you sure `state.dragging` becomes `true` in `trigger_drag()`? Your code looks like it should work. Maybe you could keep a local copy of the `dragging` flag and only use the bounded value for setting the `dragging` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier approach would be to move away from dispatching asynchronous actions and instead utilize a reusable component that handles its own state as a single object with synchronous `setState` callback updates.

For example, you can simplify your logic with two event listeners and one event callback: one event listener for `mouseup` (a mouse click) to hold the element, another event listener for `mousemove` (when holding a mouse click and moving the mouse) to translate the element, and lastly you can use the element's `onMouseDown` (mouse click release) event callback to release itself at its current position.

**Working example** (this example uses `styled-components` for cleaner code, but you don't need to):

[image: Edit Drag and Drop Content Example]

---

**components/DragContainer/index.js**

```
import styled from "styled-components";

export default styled.div.attrs(({ height, width, x, y }) => ({
  style: {
    transform: `translate(${x - width / 2}px, ${y - height / 2}px)`
  }
}))`
  cursor: grab;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;

  background-color: red;

  ${({ isDragging }) =>
    isDragging &&
    `
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor: grabbing;
    z-index: 999999;
  `}
`;
```

**components/Draggable/index.js**

```
import React, {
  useState,
  useRef,
  useEffect,
  useCallback,
  useLayoutEffect
} from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import DragContainer from "../DragContainer";

const Draggable = ({ children, position }) => {
  const dragRef = useRef(null);

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    isDragging: false,
    translateX: position.x,
    translateY: position.y,
    height: 0,
    width: 0
  });

  // mouse move
  const handleMouseMove = useCallback(
    ({ clientX, clientY }) => {
      if (state.isDragging) {
        setState(prevState => ({
          ...prevState,
          translateX: clientX,
          translateY: clientY
        }));
      }
    },
    [state.isDragging]
  );

  // mouse left click release
  const handleMouseUp = useCallback(() => {
    if (state.isDragging) {
      setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        isDragging: false
      }));
    }
  }, [state.isDragging]);

  // mouse left click hold
  const handleMouseDown = useCallback(() => {
    setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      isDragging: true
    }));
  }, []);

  // before painting, get element height and width
  // and zero out its position (this is
  // necessary to force the cursor to point at the
  // center of the element when dragging it)
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (state.height < 1 && state.width < 1) {
      const { offsetHeight, offsetWidth } = dragRef.current;
      setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        translateX: position.x + offsetWidth / 2,
        translateY: position.y + offsetHeight / 2,
        height: offsetHeight,
        width: offsetWidth
      }));
    }
  }, [position, state, setState, dragRef]);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
      window.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
    };
  }, [handleMouseMove, handleMouseUp]);

  return (
    <DragContainer
      ref={dragRef}
      isDragging={state.isDragging}
      onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
      x={state.translateX}
      y={state.translateY}
      height={state.height}
      width={state.width}
    >
      {children}
    </DragContainer>
  );
};

Draggable.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  position: PropTypes.shape({
    x: PropTypes.number,
    y: PropTypes.number
  })
};

Draggable.defaultProps = {
  position: {
    x: 10,
    y: 10
  }
};

export default Draggable;
```

**index.js**

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Draggable, Title } from "./components";

const App = () => (
  <Fragment>
    <Draggable position={{ x: 20, y: 20 }}>
      <Title>Hello</Title>
    </Draggable>
    <Draggable position={{ x: 140, y: 20 }}>
      <Title>Goodbye</Title>
    </Draggable>
  </Fragment>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your help! Plugging your Draggable into my project works, but changing everything in my DragTarget to match Draggable (useState, useCallback, remount listeners on callback changes) doesn't seem to work. I'll continue trying to figure out what's up with that, but having a working example to learn from is great!
Thank you very much!

Comment: I'd recommend keeping the event listeners active for the duration that the items are still mounted in the DOM. If you want to disable dragging, then create a button to toggle some `isDraggable` boolean state. Then, in the event listener callbacks, check that this `isDraggable` state is true to update/not update the element accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try `e => trigger_drop(e, props, dispatch)` to get the correct value and dispatch function.